# W3C validation for error

Tags: html

I have been trying to look for a solution for this W3C HTML validation error for more than I should be. I still can't figure out how to solve this. If anyone in here could help me out, that would be great.

```
Line 109, Column 27: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control. 
                    <label for="location">Location</label>

Line 162, Column 27: The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control. 
                    <label for="location">Location</label>
```

HTML CODE

```
<fieldset id="meat">
    <legend>Meat Toppings</legend>
       <label for="location">Location</label>
        <img  src="full.png" alt="full">
        <img src="left.png" alt="left">
        <img src="right.png" alt="right">
        <img id="location" src="none.png" alt="none">
```

Answer (score 1):

> The ID of a labelable form-related element in the same document as the label element. The first such element in the document with an ID matching the value of the for attribute is the labeled control for this label element.

You have no form controls in the code. The sole purpose of a label element is to label a form control. Change `<img id="location"` into a form control; input, textarea, button, or select.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a `label` is to describe a form element. When using a `label`, the `for` attribute needs to be the same as the `id` of the form element it is describing.

```
<label for="location">Location:</label><input type="text" id="location" name="location" />
```

You are getting this error because you are supplying a `for` attribute for a form element that does not exist, or is not `id`ed correctly.

Comment: it passed the validation but it messed up my fieldset..the img is supposed to be in column with location .. but now there is textarea inbetween the location and img ...

Comment: My code sample is not how to "fix" your code, it is how to properly use a `label` element. You are using it incorrectly. The `label` element is only purpose is to "represent a caption in a user interface." http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label

Comment: oahh okaii .. what kinda code do we use to link it with for attribute label when you have multiple inline images .. i am totally lost.

Comment: @user2199351 - Why do you need to link a label with an image at all? What is the underlying goal?

Comment: Giving me error when i validate. "location" needs to be link with the image which is kinda like figcaption i guess